# error about using dict to split dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The training data looks like below :

```
p,x,s,n,t,p,f,c,n,k,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,u
e,x,s,y,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,n,g
e,b,s,w,t,l,f,c,b,n,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,n,m
p,x,y,w,t,p,f,c,n,n,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,u
e,x,s,g,f,n,f,w,b,k,t,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,e,n,a,g
e,x,y,y,t,a,f,c,b,n,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,n,g
e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,g,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,n,m
```

The first column is the label about whether this mushroom is edible.(e:edible, p:poisonous)
And I want to split this data into two part by edible or not.
My code is below :

```
mushdf = pd.read_csv('agaricus-lepiota.data') #load in two data for mushroom and iris
mushdf.columns = ['edible?','cap-shape','cap-surface','cap-color','bruises?','odor',
                    'gill-attachment','gill-spacing','gill-size','gill-color',
                    'stalk-shape','stalk-root','stalk-surface-above-ring','stalk-surface-below-ring',
                    'stalk-color-above-ring','stalk-color-below-ring','veil-type','veil-color',
                    'ring-number','ring-type','spore-print-color','population','habitat']
print(mushdf)
mushdic = {key: mushdf for (key, mushdf) in mushdf.groupby('edible?')}
for key in mushdic:
    print(f'mushdic[{key}]')
    print(mushdic[key])
    print('-'*50)
```

The problem is, when I delete `mushdf.columns` in line 2 to line 6, this code works. However, when I do `mushdf.columns`, the terminal return error message.

Same method with another column is fine. For example, `mushdic = {key: mushdf for (key, mushdf) in mushdf.groupby('bruises?')}` is running correctly.

I have no idea about this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Visual Studio Project\LiMing\vs2017_python\.vscode\helloworld.py", line 11, in <module>
    mushdic = {key: mushdf for (key, mushdf) in mushdf.groupby('edible?')}
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7894, in groupby
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2522, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 391, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 621, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'edible?'
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard pandas question, and has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut Got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries; just keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) implies that your first line in the csv file is the header. Since your csv file has no header, you need to tell this during the import. You should also pass the column names here already:

```
mushdf = pd.read_csv('agaricus-lepiota.data', header=None, names=[
                'edible?','cap-shape','cap-surface','cap-color','bruises?','odor',
                'gill-attachment','gill-spacing','gill-size','gill-color',
                'stalk-shape','stalk-root','stalk-surface-above-ring','stalk-surface-below-ring',
                'stalk-color-above-ring','stalk-color-below-ring','veil-type','veil-color',
                'ring-number','ring-type','spore-print-color','population','habitat'])
```

Comment: I have been upset about this problem for hours.. It's really warm-hearted to see the answer, and it really works! Thank you with my sincerest gratefulness.